# Updating a driver quirk in kernel

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, drivers

Os : Debian 6
Kernel Version : 2.6.32

I have been recently working with Linux application and now we have some little hard-disk issues where my motherboard doesn't support AHCI through bios.
On various Google searches i found that i can force Linux kernel force load driver to AHCI mode.

i have just now started my kernel walk through and i am very new for handling issues.

THS IS THE QUIRK WHICH I FOUND WILL WORK : 
      http://tartarus.org/~ds/quirk-ich-force-ahci.patch

I download the kernel and its respective headers and did a complete kernel build.since its Debian updated it in the client machine and found it was working as expected

```
  linux-image-2.6.32_2.6.32-2_i386.deb -- 26MB
  linux-firmware-image_2.6.32-2_all.deb -- 5k
```

but now i need to apply the patch in all my client machines which i located n remote locations where 26 mb in the network is very high

Is there a way where only this quirk can be updated in client in a reduce size like some KO file update.

Is this the only way way to update the driver??
need some guidelines on the same.

i also saw : http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/add-remove-list-linux-kernel-modules/

Comment: Place that in a museum, and get an up-to-date installation?

Comment: @vonbrand : Oh i c